# Java Character.MATH_SYMBOL to C# conversion

Tags: c#

.NET 4.6.1 C#

I found a possible solution to a problem I'm having. The solution is written in Java. I converted 99% of it to C# easily, sans 1 line. Here's the synopsis.

They have a string that is converted to a character array. Here's the C# equivalent:

```
   string pFormula = "my string";
   char[] tokens = pFormula.ToCharArray();
```

Then the following line of code occurs (this is Java):

```
   if (Character.getType(tokens[i]) == Character.MATH_SYMBOL){
     //do something
    }
```

This is where i'm stuck. I can do this:

```
     tokens[i].GetType() //Character.getType(tokens[i])
```

Does anyone know the C# equivalent of java's Character.MATH_SYMBOL? Thanks

Comment: @SajalDutta this will return true for $ too, but this is not math symbol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char plus = '+';

if(char.GetUnicodeCategory(plus) == UnicodeCategory.MathSymbol)
{
    //return true
}
```

You need to use [UnicodeCategory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Be aware not every symbol which can be used in Math is in UnicodeCategory.MathSymbol. *** and / are not part of MathSybols**

```
char a2 = '*';

if(char.GetUnicodeCategory(a2) == UnicodeCategory.OtherPunctuation)
{
    //return true, but return false for Math.
}
```

Here how it looks like the unicode character for multiplication and division used in MathSymbols.

```
 char multiplication = '×';
 char division = '÷';
```

Here this should be [List of characters in unicode designation Sm(symbol,math)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response. What this is for is excel speadsheet formulas. We do not get too fancy, so the standard +-*/ might be sufficient. Thanks